ElectronForge + Webpack + native addon not working
I've built a native nodejs addon using cpp and compiled it using node-gyp. If I copy the *.node file into my ElectronJS app and run it from my PC it works perfectly, the issue begins when I package the app and try to run it from another PC. I'm getting the following error:

... "error":{"code":"ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED"},"exception":true,"level":"\u001b[31merror\u001b[39m","message":"uncaughtException: The specified module could not be found.\r\n\\\\?\\C:\\Users\\Test\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\a2eb239f-e0f1-43f3-9ac2-327aab2d0178.tmp.node\nError: The specified module could not be found.\r\n\\\\?\\C:\\Users\\Test\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\a2eb239f-e0f1-43f3-9ac2-327aab2d0178.tmp.node\n    at process.func [as dlopen] (node:electron/js2c/node_init:2:2214)\n ...

I understand it must be how Webpack bundles the app together. I have tried many approaches to solve the issues, right now the addon is right at the root:

And in Webpack's index.js it looks like this: e.exports=require("./h5addon.node")}
I've tried Using Node.js addons in Electron's renderer with Webpack
and this https://github.com/smt116/node-native-ext-loader
and this https://github.com/webpack-contrib/node-loader/issues/46
I appreciate any help in this regard, I've no idea what else to do.
Thank you.
